# Como pegar um valor de um select (edit) Laravel

Tags: laravel

bom dia, alguém pode me ajudar nesse select, (exemplo: Usuario vai cadastrar e lá ele seleciona o cliente já cadastrado).

então vai ter os inputs para preencher mas o select, OK!

agora ele vai alterar o form, como eu consigo trazer o valor selecionado

**editar.blade.php**

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h2>Alterar Apontamento</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="{{route('equipe.alterar.apontamento', ['id' => $apontamento->id])}}" method="post">
                        @csrf <!--protecao-->
                            @method('put')
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
                                <select name="cliente" id="cliente" class="form-control" >
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
                                    @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
                                        <option  value="{{$cliente->id}}">{{$cliente->user->name}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('cliente')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="servicos">Serviços</label>
                                <select name="servicos" id="servicos" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
                                    @foreach($servicos as $servico)
                                        <option value="{{$servico->id}}">{{$servico->nome}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('servicos')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="inicio">Hora inicio:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inicio" id="inicio" value="{{$apontamento->inicio}}">
                                @error('inicio')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="termino">Término:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="termino" id="termino" value="{{$apontamento->termino}}">
                                @error('termino')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="considerado">Considerado:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="considerado" id="considerado" value="{{$apontamento->considerado}}">
                                @error('considerado')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="atividade">Atividade:</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="atividade" id="atividade" value="{{$apontamento->atividade}}">
                                @error('atividade')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="observacao">Observação</label>
                                <textarea type="text" rows="6" class="form-control" name="observacao" id="observacao" value="{{$apontamento->observacao}}"></textarea>
                                @error('observacao')
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </div>

                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Alterar</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**controller**

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $apontamento = Apontamento::with('user')->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('apontamento.editar', compact('apontamento'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param int $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $apontamento = Apontamento::find($id);
        $clientes = Cliente::find();
        $servicos = Servicos::find();

        $apontamento->atividade = $request->atividade;
        $apontamento->inicio = $request->inicio;
        $apontamento->termino = $request->termino;
        $apontamento->considerado = $request->considerado;
        $apontamento->observacao = $request->observacao;
        $clientes->cliente_id = $request->cliente;
        $servicos->servico_id = $request->servicos;
            $apontamento->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisa comparar o valor que armazena o cliente selecionado no cadastro e comparar com os valores que estão gerando esse `SELECT` e adicione atributo `selected` para posicionar, exemplo:

```
 @if ($cliente->id === $apontamento->cliente_id) { 'selected'; } @endif
```

**Completo**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cliente">Cliente</label>
    <select name="cliente" id="cliente" class="form-control" >
        <option value="" selected>Selecione</option>
        @foreach($clientes as $cliente)
            <option  value="{{$cliente->id}}" @if ($cliente->id === $apontamento->cliente_id) { 'selected'; } @endif >{{$cliente->user->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
    @error('cliente')
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Comment: vê se meu controller esta certo..

Comment: consegui, mudei controller $clientes = Cliente::all();

Comment: @FernandoSqse não entendi

Comment: deu certo rsrsrs

Comment: Então se for útil @FernandoSqse sinalize como resposta pra o sua pergunta